# Vcenter Options missing

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I'm just new to the Vcenter 6.5 webclient. I can't seem to find some options which the VMWARE documentation refers to. E.g. I can't see the 'Access', 'Firewall', 'Networking' for the Vcenter under System Configuration -> Nodes -> Manage.

Under Manage it just shows me Settings and Certificate Authority and under settings there is only an option to leave or join Active Directory.

Am I missing anything or do I need to activate something.

Comment: Does your user have the proper permissions to view these sections?

Comment: yes i'm using the administrator@vspshere.local account